# Problem with center of mass in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, spherical-coordinates

When we calculate center of mass using rectangular coordinates, we find the average values in each coordinate. Obviously we can't do this very same thing in polar coordinates: if we integrated a constant density on a disk, we'd end up with a positive "average $r$" value, which doesn't make any sense.

What is the fundamental reason why the averaging coordinates works in the former case but not the latter? I suppose it showcases a fundamental difference between rectangular and spherical coordinates.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ coordinates are linear functionals on $\mathbb R^2$, but $r$ and $\theta$ are not.

Comment: @pizza And I guess that "the additive structure we put on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plays nice with the additions of force" is a datum of physics that is more or less experimental? I suppose Newton's laws are intimately tied up with rectangular coordinates?

Comment: The question refers to center of mass, not to forces... I think the center of mass is defined mathematically, e.g., as a point $r_0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i-r_0)=0$.... This being a linear relation. Newton's laws also impose linearity of some sorts: e.g., mass is additive.

Comment: @pizza What are $r_i$ and $r_0$ in relation to mass? I guess it would be the mass of the element times its distance from the center?

Comment: I forgot to put masses there.  $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i (r_i-r_0)=0$.